# Cron jobs output on console

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have written a shell script (`myscript.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
ls
pwd
```

I want to schedule this job for every minute and it should display on the console. In order to do that I have done `crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * * /root/myscript.sh
```

Here, it's display the output in the file `/var/mail/root` rather than printing on the console.

What changes I have to make inorder to print the output on console?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I can think of is to log the output to disk and have a console window constantly checking to see if the logfile has been altered and printing the changes.

crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /root/myscript.sh | tee -a /path/to/logfile.log
```

in console:

```
tail -F /path/to/logfile.log
```

The problem with this is that you will get an ever growing log file which will need to be periodically deleted.

To avoid this you would have to do something more complicated whereby you identify the console pid that you wish to write to and store this in a predefined place.

console script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# register.sh script    
# prints parent pid to special file

echo $PPID > /path/to/predfined_location.txt
```

wrapper script for crontab

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cmd=$1
remote_pid_location=$2

# Read the contents of the file into $remote_pid.
# Hopefully the contents will be the pid of the process that wants the output 
# of the command to be run.
read remote_pid < $remote_pid_location

# if the process still exists and has an open stdin file descriptor
if stat /proc/$remote_pid/fd/0 &>/dev/null
then
    # then run the command echoing it's output to stdout and to the
    # stdin of the remote process
    $cmd | tee /proc/$remote_pid/fd/0 
else
    # otherwise just run the command as normal
    $cmd
fi
```

crontab usage:

```
*/1 * * * * /root/wrapper_script.sh /root/myscript.sh /path/to/predefined_location.txt
```

Now all you have to do is run `register.sh` in the console you want the program to print to.

Comment: Can we print the output periodically after every minute on the screen rather than redirecting into the file?

Comment: So you want to essentially capture the entire output and then suddenly print all of it your console at once? Did you try the second solution which doesn't redirect to a file?

Comment: I had followed the same procedure which you have mentioned. But it is giving the message like 
/bin/sh: /root/crontest/wrapper.sh: Permission denied
in /var/mail/root. I am not able to understand why it is giving this one.

Comment: mostly like that you haven't given execute permissions to wrapper.sh

Comment: I had given the execute permissions now and tried to execute register.sh
It is showing in /var/mail/root like this,
/root/crontest/wrapper.sh: line 6: /root/crontest/register.txt: No such file or directory
and displaying the output of "ls,pwd" 




Actually i had one doubt , Is that i have to place myscript.sh in console.sh where you commented like # register.sh

Comment: The wrapper script is complaining that register.txt does not exist. Does it exist? Have you run register.sh yet?

Comment: i thought that it will create automatically, so i didn't created the file register.txt

Now, I created the file register.txt . But now when i run register.sh it is showing "command not found", but the output is redirecting to the file /var/mail/root for every one min.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to achieve the output of a cron job to a gnome terminal , and managed it by this

```
*/1 * * * * /root/myscript.sh > /dev/pts/0
```

I suppose if you do not have a GUI and you only have CLI you might use

```
*/1 * * * * /root/myscript.sh > /dev/tty1
```

to achieve the output of a crontab job to be redirected to your console. But first be sure to find the name of your terminal. if it is /dev/tty1 or something else. I am not sure how this can be done for all cases, probably with something like

```
env | grep -i tty
```

Comment: I had high hopes, but I tried `*/1 * * * * date > /dev/tty1` on a raspberry pi running buster lite and saw no output.

Comment: First check what is your active terminal session name. Maybe something like

env | grep -i tty

Comment: Full marks.  /dev/pts/0 worked for CLI.  Thank you

Comment: Which terminal to output to is a hard problem in the general case. If your system only has one user,  you can't go too far in the wrong direction, but in general, you can't be sure that the user is logged in at all, and if they are, which terminal sessions they are paying attention to. You should probably look for a different way to solve your problem (`cron` sends its output by email by default, which makes sense for many scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use "wall" in your script to display a message to all terminals. E.G.

```
wall -n Display this message to all terminals.
```